# C#: String Manipulation WildCard Search

Tags: search, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, wildcard

I am creating a search application which searches a collection from a given string + *

For example I have this string collection:

> **SMITH**
>
> **SMATH**
>
> **BATH**
>
> **SMAG**
>
> **x**
>
> **Test**

When the user input ***TH** the output should be SMITH, SMATH and BATH

When the user input **SM*TH** the output should be SMITH and SMATH

When the user input **SM*** the output should be SMITH, SMATH and SMAG

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest using regex for this.. refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match and http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Your spec is incomplete.  Would you expect the string "SMTH" to match "SM*TH"?  IOW, can * represent a zero-length string?

Comment: * represents single character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in .NET

If you only have a wildcard * I'd probably replace this with a .* (0 or more characters) or a .+ (1 or more characters) in the first instance

something like (not tested but should have all the elements to get you going)

```
var pattern = "SM*TH"; 
var newpattern = pattern.Replace("*",".+"); 
var rex = new RegEx(newpattern); 
var match = rex.Match("SMITH")
```

Comment: Can you please give an example on how to do it since I dont have a constant pattern? Thanks

Comment: var pattern = "SM*TH";
var newpattern = pattern.Replace("*",".+");
var rex = new RegEx(newpattern);
var match = rex.Match("SMITH");

Comment: Can you please expound it? For example I have str1 = "SMITH" and the search input is str2 = "SM*". How do I put it to code using Regex? thanks

Comment: str2 is the same as pattern (i.e. the thing you are looking for) PS. don't be afraid to give your variables sensible names

Comment: thanks Shaun, however, it is not working if the pattern = "*x" and the match string is x only. It returns empty search.

Comment: also, i added Test in my collection. pattern = "T*" however the results were all string which contains "T" wherein it should only be results starts with "T"

Comment: have you tried .* (0 or more) instead of .+ (1 or more) as I described earlier - have a look at the links posted and get a feeling regular expressions, they are quite powerful utility.